# Where’s the equivalent of Yellow paper for Ethereum classic?

Tags: ethereum-classic, yellow-paper

Ethereum classic performed changes never implemented on Ethereum like on mining. I do expect them to have their own paper for detailing this.
But it seems it’s not called the yellow paper…

Even on their Github’s user page and their GitHub’s Website I failed to find it…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Yellow Paper for Ethereum Classic is... the Ethereum Yellow Paper.

The first version of the Yellow Paper was released in 2014.

Ethereum Classic split from the original chain at block 1,920,000 (theDAO hardfork), 20th July 2016.

The [more recent](https://gavwood.com/paper.pdf), [easy-to-find](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) PDF versions of the Yellow Paper have additions which don't apply to ETC, so you'll need to do the following:

- look back at the [revision history](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/commits) on GitHub for the final version that was released prior to the chain split;
- apply any relevant [ECIP](https://ecips.ethereumclassic.org/) additions/changes.

Comment: Except Ethereum classic performed changes never implemented on Ethereum like on mining. I do expect them to have their own paper for detailing this.

Comment: Those changes are detailed in the relevant ECIPs, which is the second bullet-point. The (accepted/finalised) ECIPs act as addenda to the Yellow Paper at the point the two chains split.

Comment: And they didn t set up an alternate paper detailling the implemented ecip?

Comment: I imagine there are several things they need to consider. a) How permissive the licence on the Yellow Paper is (I haven't checked - it's probably fine though), b) the effort required to ensure any updates are mathematically sound (the Yellow Paper has to be academically rigorous), c) whether it's worth going through the process of updating the paper for the relatively minor changes in the ECIPs. Further to c), updates would have to be made each time a new ECIP is approved.

Comment: Writing a whole new paper from scratch would be pointless, as 99% of it would be identical to an earlier version of the original YP. As I mentioned in my first comment, you could argue that the ECIPs are themselves "papers" which act as additions to the original YP.